# Variable table name in dynamic sql with COALESCE

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, dynamic-sql

I want to get columnnaes of a table in a variable in this form `col1,col2,col3`

So I used following query

```
SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ', ', '') + column_name FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_CATALOG='mudb' and TABLE_NAME='mytbl'
```

**I have been successful with above**. But when i want to use **variable table name**. I get problem. I tried

```
SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ', ', '') + column_name FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_CATALOG='mudb' and TABLE_NAME=@tbl
```

But it gives null result. Then I teid to use `EXECUTE sp_executesql`

```
set @FullStatement='SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + '', '', '''') +
column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_CATALOG=''mudb''
and TABLE_NAME=@tbl'

PRINT @FullStatement
EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullStatement
```

Then it gives me error `Must declare the scalar variable "@cols"` but @cols is declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@cols` may be declared in the scope of the script you are running.  It is not declared in the scope of the dynamic SQL.  Variables are not inherited from one level to another.

So, you want to pass it into the execution environment, which you can do with `sp_executesql`:

```
set @FullStatement='SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + '', '', '''') +
column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_CATALOG=''mudb''
and TABLE_NAME=@tbl'

PRINT @FullStatement
EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullStatement, N'@Cols varchar(8000) output, @Tbl varchar(8000)',
                      @cols = @cols, @tbl = 'MyTable';
```

That is how you get the execute statement to work.  However, that method of concatenating column will not work in dynamic SQL.

Comment: now says \@tbl not delared, \@cols not delared.Actually i just want to get same output with variable table name as by my first code

Comment: Thanks to tbl error.. I have just set @tbl='mytbl' (though stored procedure is already receiving value for it but it was not working) and now i got my result with my 2nd code (dynamic table name)